# Why does mysql_client_encoding() return "latin1" when MySQL is configured with "UTF8"?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, character-set

When I run `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE  'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE  'collation%'` in MySQL, I get the following variables:

```
Variable_name               Value
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database      utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        utf8mb4
character_set_system        utf8
collation_connection        utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database          utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server            utf8mb4_general_ci
```

However, when I run a simple test to connect to MySQL in PHP **without** setting *any* encoding, `mysql_client_encoding()` returns `latin1`, yet that encoding is nowhere to be found in the MySQL character sets.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it so that I don't have to continually specify `mysql_set_charset('UTF8');` every time I connect to MySQL?

Comment: Don't use PHP's `mysql_*` API.